# Why is dropdown returning incorrect value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, input

I'm having an issue where I'm using jQuery to get the value of a drop down, however, it is only returning the value that was originally selected. The page is written with php and gets values from a database. If a select element is previously selected, then the option with that value has the selected attribute put on it. This results in something like this:

```
<select name="dropdown1">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2" selected>2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

The problem that I'm having with the javascript is that no matter what gets selected, the option that has the selected attribute to start is always returned as the value for that input. It doesn't matter what option is actually selected, option 2 is always returned as the selected element. Here is the javascript that I'm using.

```
    $.each( inputs, function( key, value ){
        var element = $( "[name='" + key + "']" );
        var this_val = $( element ).val();
        console.log( this_val ); //always returns 2
    });
```

The variable inputs is an associative array with key and value pairs that match input names in the form. Any help you could provide on why this is happening would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please creating a functioning example on http://jsfiddle.net/ I do not understand the problem. Please include the actions that trigger the `$.each` to be called.

Comment: Show us what's in your `inputs` collection...

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/PTkKR/5/

Comment: Yeah thats the problem I'm having. I tried to get everything into a jsfiddle but it wasn't reproducing the problem. Working to get an example to show.

Comment: Each element in inputs is something like this "student_physical_address1": "student_mailing_address1" its an array of corresponding input names.

Answer (score 0):

If you did something like `var inputs = $('select')`, then `key` is a subscript into the array of `select` nodes, not an actual node name. However, `value` represents the node that corresponds to `key`, so you can just do `var element = $( "[name='" + value.name + "']" );`